# replacing parts of string using regular expression match in python

Tags: python, regex

In python,
I have to  replace every occurance of `(a is b)`  with  `(a,b)`   [where a,b are non-null strings , observe that paranthesis are a part of substring]  in a string s . 
I am planning to use `re` module .. but I am stuck with how to preserve a,b in the replacement string ..How can I do this?

```
Ex:  "you know that (tiger is animal) and kiwi is bird"
     output : "you know that (tiger,animal) and kiwi is bird"
```

matching regex is :

```
 r"\([a-z]+\sis\s[a-z]+\)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use capturing groups and backreferences:

```
re.sub(r"\(([a-z]+)\sis\s([a-z]+)\)", r"(\1,\2)", text)
```

Answer (score 3):

`re` is a better solution for your case:

```
>>> pat_sub = re.compile(r'(?<=\()\s*?(?P<X>[a-z]+)\s*?is\s*?(?P<Y>[a-z]+)\s*?(?=\))')
>>> 
>>> pat_sub.sub(r'\g<X>,\g<Y>',s)
'you know that (tiger,animal) and kiwi is bird'
>>> 
>>> s
'you know that (tiger is animal) and kiwi is bird'
```

See break-out of regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/fE7rM6/4) with different examples.

Comment: Ah..then in that case `re` is a better solution as it will increase complexity of code with built-in method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
re.sub(r'(^\([^\s]+)\s+is\s+(.+$)', r'\1,\2', input)
```